How to correctly link an asset file in a library compiled by dartsass-rails used in a rails app
I am currently using the dartsass-rails lib in compiling scss files in my rails app. In the lib, I have a customized font family I'm trying to create using @font-face and a local font file;
@font-face {
  font-family: "FooBar";
  src: url("../foo.woff");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

On compilation, the scss file is compiled into a public path. On page load, the path to the font file that was declared as seen above is not found and throws 404.
How can I solve this so that the font file is correctly linked and is found on runtime?

You are not in a relative path.
What i usually do is create a fonts directory inside app/assets and inside an other directory for each font.
At the end i have something like /app/assets/fonts/roboto and inside i get all the files.
Then at the config/application.rb i add this line to add fonts as assets.
    config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")

And in the scss files i use it like this, following the example with roboto:
@font-face {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  src: url("roboto/normal.woff");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

I don't know if i forgot something, let me know.

I get this. but the issue is that the @font-face code is in a library. The library should be independent of how the user choses to compile

Oh sorry, miss read.  The files of the library are inside your assets right ?

no. they are inside the library as well

Is this a possible solution ?
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/31266#issuecomment-587448103
If not, specify in the post the package manager, file schema, or other thighs that can be useful to understand the problem, or at least reproduce it.

Thing is the dartsass-rails lib doesn't really work with the rails asset pipeline
